# Get the number of points in a bucket for a time interval with Flux query

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

Given a bucket how do I get the number of points in this bucket with the timestamp in the given time interval using a Flux query?

I'm trying to estimate how much data is added to an influxdb2 bucket per unit of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
from(bucket: "mybucket")
  |> range(start: -1m)
  |> group()  
  |> count()
```

In my case there's a very big number of series (table streams returned by from) in the bucket so I had to add group() with no arguments to combine it into a single table before count(). It would return the count for each table separately otherwise.

From the flux manual:

> An empty group key groups all data in a stream of tables into a single
> table

Answer (score 3):

I think it should look something like this:

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measurement")
  |> window(period: 30s)
  |> group(columns: ["_start"])
  |> count()
```

At the first we separete out data by time window `|> window(period: 30s)`
Then we group by new `_start` time and get count of records.

Comment: thanks! in my case there's a very big number of series (table streams returned by `from`) in the bucket so I had to add group() with no arguments to combine it into a single table before count()

Comment: @axk Yes, my initial answer/query was the same as yours, but then I saw in your question a clarification about `per unit of time` and added `window` for that. Anyway I was glad to help :)